# Can Service Worker or FetchEvent Detect or Listen for "stop" events?

Tags: service-worker, fetch-api, service-worker-events

Can a Service Worker or `FetchEvent` detect when a "stop" event is triggered by the user?  For example, users could stop the page from loading images with the browser's stop button is clicked (or with `window.stop()` JavaScript). I would like my Service Worker to detect that event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not something that's exposed to the service worker as an event.

If you believe that it should be, [filing a feature request](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues) against the specification would be the right first step.

Comment: Thanks. I'll file a new request.  Also filed a related issue: https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/3525